# Make a file hidden from a batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

Does anyone know how I can use the batch code to hide a file? This is my code:

```
@echo off
start ChromePass.exe /stext ChromePass.txt
start iepv.exe /stext iepv.txt
start mailpv.exe /stext mailpv.txt
start mspass.exe /stext mspass.txt
start OperaPassView.exe /stext OperaPassView.txt
start PasswordFox.exe /stext PasswordFox.txt
start WebBrowserPassView.exe /stext WebBrowserPassView.txt
```

These are programs for password recovery. I have a lot of passwords, saved in my browsers, and e-mail clients. I need to make the text file hidden, because there are multiple other people who use my laptop, and I do not want them to find out my passwords (mainly because I have accounts on websites that my parents don't want me having).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`attrib`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true)

`attrib WebBrowserPassView.txt +h`

`+h` means add the hidden attribute to the file. `-h` would remove it.

You should consider moving these files to a secure location. **Security through obscurity is not advised** since we are dealing with passwords.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about that code, but could not figure out how to use it. I do not currently have a secure location, but I may be getting my own computer soon.

Comment: I just tried it, but it just created a file called attrib with no extension.

Comment: That code would work. Make sure you are in the same directory when you are creating the files. While in command prompt you can use `dir -ah` to view the hidden files -a for attribute and h for hidden. What is the exact command you tried?

Comment: I used the code you posted: attrib WebBrowserPassView.txt +h

Comment: `Attrib` cant create files so im at a loss as to what is happening. What are is the result of the other command `dir -ah`?

Comment: "H:\New folder>dir -ah
 Volume in drive H is USB20FD
 Volume Serial Number is 0F55-CFA8

 Directory of H:\New folder

File Not Found" (I am currently using a cheap flash drive in case I screw something up"

Comment: So you have to hidden files so far there is what that tells me. Run these commands for me (between the quotes)(this is on your local c:) 1."cd c:\temp",2."echo 'Just a test' > somefile.txt",3."attrib somefile.txt +h",4."dir -ah". Is there any output from `dir` now? Again, test this in your c:\temp directory.

Comment: When I type "cd c:\temp", it says it cannot find the path specified. I changed it to "c:\Windows\temp" and it worked, but after step 3, it says parameter not found.

Comment: So you dont have a c:\temp directory which is fine. From the sounds of it though do you have a hidden file in c:\Windows\temp called somefile.txt? You can right click on it and select properties to check the flag.

Comment: Matt's answer is right.  If it created a file then you have a batch file or other executable called `attrib` that is modifying the result.  You need admin permissions to write to some folders and a fully qualified path if the file is not in the current working directory.

Comment: I have admin rights, but Windows 8 sometime says that I do not. I do not have any hidden files in that folder. I have Windows Explorer set to show hidden files.

Comment: let me guess, you tried to use the attrib a a sort of modifier to your commandlines? like `start WebBrowserPassView.exe /stext attrib WebBrowserPassView.txt +h` ? you have to put the `attrib WebBrowserPassView.txt +h` *after* each of the original lines from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using stream:

<kbd>Hide.bat</kbd>

```
@echo off
more < file.txt > fileB.txt:stream1
pause
```

- Read from `file.txt` and echo the content into `fileB.txt`'s stream1
- Note:

### Normal file explorer/ text editor can see the file, but cannot read the content inside it

<kbd>Read.bat</kbd>

```
@echo off
more < fileB.txt:stream1 
pause
```

- Read `fileB.txt`'s content **from stream1**

See: https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html