# How can I hide a symbolic link rather than the file it points to in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to hide a file using a batch script, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25354491/6335363) (`attrib +h myfile.txt`). However, as my file is a symbolic link (pointing to `elsewhere/myfile.txt`), the target `elsewhere/myfile.txt` file is hidden rather than the symbolic link.

How can I make the `attrib` command modify the symbolic link (`myfile.txt`), rather than the target of the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you should use the [`/l` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib#parameters), which tells `attrib` to modify the link rather than its target.

In your case, the modified command is `attrib +h myfile.txt /l`.